# How to solve Error:apache shutdown unexceptedly?

Tags: xampp

I have tried every thing in that stack overflow,even after it is showing the same error. Please can anyone provide an answer for this problem?

Comment: I could provide us with more information about what you tried? What is exactly everything on SO?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want a good quality response it is best to take the time to craft a good quality question. But in general, you need to provide a lot more information about what has been tried and to theorise about what might be wrong. But asking one line questions that don't demonstrate any effort using 'mobile-phone-speak' instead of real worlds is not going to be received well by the community. Please take a look at these helpful tips: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for that output but here's the way you can know for sure

- Open `cmd` by pressing, `Win + R` and typing `cmd`
- `cd` into apache / bin directory eg. `"C:/xampp/apache/bin"`
- Now type `httpd.exe` to start apache

If there's a problem, it would output the error in the console and then you can correct it.